# How to sum up every n elements of a Scala array?

Tags: arrays, scala, sum

what's the efficient way to sum up every n elements of an array in Scala? For example, if my array is like below:

```
val arr = Array(3,1,9,2,5,8,...)
```

and I want to sum up every 3 elements of this array and get a new array like below:

```
newArr = Array(13, 15, ...)
```

How can I do this efficiently in Spark Scala? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grouped` followed by `map` should do the trick:

```
scala> val arr = Array(3,1,9,2,5,8)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(3, 1, 9, 2, 5, 8)

scala> arr.grouped(3).map(_.sum).toArray
res0: Array[Int] = Array(13, 15)
```

Comment: @Carter, did yo really mean Spark Scala? As RDDs don't have `grouped`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `toIterator` method on the array before calling `grouped` should speed things up a bit, i.e.

```
arr.toIterator.grouped(3).map(_.sum).toArray
```

For example, using

```
val xs = Array.range(0, 10000)
```

10000 iterations of

```
xs.toIterator.grouped(3).map(_.sum).toArray
```

takes about 16.93 seconds, while 10000 iterations of

```
xs.grouped(3).map(_.sum).toArray
```

requires approximately 21.49 seconds.